# Is there any way to cast a Context to an Activity directly inside the constructor with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, casting

Is there any way to cast a Context to an Activity directly inside the constructor?

Something like that :

```
class CustomView(mainActivity: MainActivity, attrs: AttributeSet?) : SurfaceView(mainActivity, attrs) {
    fun draw() {
        mainActivity.foo()
        ...
    }
}
```

In order to avoid casting it in every methods :

```
class CustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : SurfaceView(context, attrs) {
    fun draw() {
        val mainActivity = context as MainActivity
        mainAcitivity.foo()
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be done but generally a custom view should not care about its container. Consider making the main activity (or any other container) update the custom view rather than the custom view calling to the main activity.

Comment: I understand. I need to refresh a view from an action performed on another view. (click on A refresh B). Can I do it without passing by the container (mainActivity.view.B.refresh())?

Comment: Sounds like something for an observer pattern coordinated by the container, e.g. stateflo,  livedata or plain old callback. Observe changes in A, update B.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class CustomView(private val activity: MainActivity) {
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context as MainActivity)
}
```

Please note that it is generally a bad idea to store an activity instead of the context object itself because then you are tightly coupling your CustomView Class with your activity which can cause all sorts of problems.

Please consider changing the design so that these classes are not tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do just this instead which would be an improvement on casting it every method

```
class CustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : SurfaceView(context, attrs) {
    private val mainActivity = context as MainActivity
    fun draw() {
        mainActivity.foo()
    }
}
```

Or to make it more safe use a safe cast like this

```
class CustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : SurfaceView(context, attrs) {
    private val mainActivity = context as? MainActivity
    fun draw() {
        mainActivity?.foo()
    }
}
```